# Angular material styles are not being applied correctly

Tags: css, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-material

I just added styles.css file, but the project is created with scss style configuration. I don't know how to have the styles back on my controls.

Comment: Please help me, i am a new in angular, everything was working correctly after i added styles.css to angular.json, but just now the styes stopped to apply. I don't know what to do to have my material styles back

Comment: could you further describe what part doesn't work?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please, read this guide on how to submit a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, the problem is with the view, when the page loads, all the regular styles on mat-form-field fade out and i can only aknowledge them by placeholder texts that appear on the page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

When the application stylesheet is changed within the Angular application, a reference to the Material themes are likely to be in the original stylesheet that contained the imported theme when Material was installed. This can explain why the build and rendered component scripts do not include Material CSS that are still within the original stylesheet.

To fix this issue, try one of the following:

The Angular Material theme is visible when it is included in one of the following areas of your application:

1. In `Angular.json`, within the styles section add the location of the
   Material theme CSS file:

   "styles": [
   "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
   "src/styles.css"
   ],
2. In `styles.css` import one of the Material CSS themes as shown:

   @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

Rebuild the application so that the referenced styles are bundled into the scripts.